# Clear WebBrowser Control Cache in .Net 3.5 Compact Framework

Tags: c#, caching, windows-ce

I need to create a Kiosk application for an old Windows CE device.

The application uses a [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx) to display product information that is scanned using the built-in barcode reader.

When the device sits idle, product ads are displayed in this [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx).

```
private void Browser_Load(string documentText)
{
    //Program.ClearBrowserCache();
    pnlBrowser_Web.DocumentText = documentText;
    pnlBrowser_Web.Update();
    pnlBrowser.BringToFront();
    pnlHeader_txtBarcode.Focus();
    _browseStart = DateTime.Now;
}
```

The problem is, after it sits there for a day or two loading and displaying product ads, it runs out of memory - apparently because the browser never dumps its cache.

[Microsoft's KB326201](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326201) goes into how to clear the cache for the [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx), but the **CallingConvention** specified there is **CallingConvention.StdCall**, but all .NET CF has is **CallingConvention.Winapi**.

I tried using **Winapi** in the commented out section "ClearBrowserCache()", but the `while loop` below never exits (no errors, but it never exits):

```
while(true)
{
    // Delete a particular Cache Group.
    returnValue = DeleteUrlCacheGroup(groupId, CACHEGROUP_FLAG_FLUSHURL_ONDELETE, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (!returnValue && ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
    {   
        returnValue = FindNextUrlCacheGroup(enumHandle, ref groupId, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    if (!returnValue && (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() || ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()))
        break;
}
```

### Does anyone know of a way to clear the cache on a Windows CE WebBrowser Control?

Comment: In Windows CE and the .NET CF, `Winapi` means the cdecl calling convention, but this should not be an issue as `DeleteUrlCacheGroup` would also use cdecl in Windows CE. When you say 'no errors', do you mean that `DeleteUrlCacheGroup` returns TRUE, or that `DeleteUrlCacheGroup` returns FALSE and `GetLastWin32Error` returns ERROR_SUCCESS?

Comment: @CarstenHansen - **DeleteUrlCacheGroup** always returns TRUE. I left it running overnight, and it was still returning TRUE the next morning. Thanks for the *cdecl* calling convention tip! I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: The company I work for said this project is taking too long, so they shelved it and returned the Windows CE device.

Comment: I am interested in how you got the WebBrowser to work in CF3.5 in the first place: see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464452/webbrowser-in-compact-framework

Comment: @bvdb - it looks like I did not keep that code. I created a new VS2008 CE project and dropped the [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx) onto the main form from the toolbar. My current employer does not have VS2008, though.