# Webbrowser in compact framework

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, compact-framework

I would like to use a `WebBrowser` component in a .NET Compact Framework 3.5 project. I am confronted with contradictive information about this.

If I just try to use it, I get the following exception:

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.
at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase..ctor(String clsidString)
at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser..ctor()
at dce.pd.dialogmgr.baseimpl.DialogDeviceImpl.createGui(XmlElement pDialogManagerNode) in C:\sourceview\CS.NETCF.2008\dce\pd\dialogmgr\baseimpl\DialogDeviceImpl.cs:line 362
at dce.pd.dialogmgr.baseimpl.DialogDeviceImpl.init() in C:\sourceview\CS.NETCF.2008\dce\pd\dialogmgr\baseimpl\DialogDeviceImpl.cs:line 118
at dce.pd.dialogmgr.thinimpl.ThinClient.createDeviceImpl() in C:\sourceview\CS.NETCF.2008\dce\pd\dialogmgr\thinimpl\ThinClient.cs:line 82
at dce.pd.dialogmgr.thinimpl.ThinClient.init() in C:\sourceview\CS.NETCF.2008\dce\pd\dialogmgr\thinimpl\ThinClient.cs:line 87
at dce.pd.dialogmgr.thinimpl.ThinClient.form_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\sourceview\CS.NETCF.2008\dce\pd\dialogmgr\thinimpl\ThinClient.cs:line 66
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

To me, this sounds like I have to put the `[STAThread]` directive to my `Main` method.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
  ...
}
```

But that doesn't work neither, because [the [STAThread] option is not available in compact framework.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5b637f4-56f6-417a-a004-851c8e7ca01f/stathread-can-not-be-found-but-where-is-it?forum=netfxcompact). So, the application won't even compile now.

Nevertheless, according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/hardware/ms229657(v=vs.85).aspx), the `WebBrowser` components is available for compact framework project. There are even some examples. (Unfortunately the full code is not provided).

So, what am I missing ?

Comment: What are you developing this project in? When I used the [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx), I was developing in Visual Studio 2008. VS2010 and newer does not have support for the .Net CF.

Comment: it's in Visual Studio 2008 , with compact framework 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what's wrong here.

In fact, the exception above (i.e. `System.Threading.ThreadStateException: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.`) only shows up when I try to run the compiled executable directly on my laptop.

**The simulator wasn't working for me.** And I finally got the simulator working now. I realized that I had to select an "emulator" device, the kind that ends with "emulator" in its name. (e.g. "Windows Mobile 6 Emulator"). You need to connect these devices before testing, using the "connect to device" button in the toolbar. Once the connection is made, **the application actually runs just fine on the emulator.**

**The question remains: *why doesn't the application run directly on my laptop while it does run fine in an emulator*. But that's a different question.**

Of course the operating system is different. But I have the impression, that the system uses a different version of the .NET framework. Previously **I wrongfully assumed that all compact framework apps could also run on a laptop with the full blown .net framework.** Now it appears that this is incorrect.

Comment: As commented in your other question, only simple CF apps will run on desktop. The CF webbrowser component differs to the FF one. The CF one is not registered on desktop and your app tries to load the FF one, giving the STA exception. Registering the CF webbrowser COM will not work on desktop (I assume so). If an CF app uses CF only APIs (like aygshell related ones) it will not run on desktop. Not every CF will run on desktop!

Comment: Yes, what I learned later was that the webbrowser component CAN ONLY run in an `[STAThread]` on full windows, and CAN ONLY in `[MTAThread]` on a real mobile device. Fortunately it is possible to detect the appartment state at startup and it can still be modified using reflection. But that's out of scope for this question. And fortunately the emulator simulates this behaviour perfectly.